# IBus avro Bangla writing problem in libre office

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I've properly installed iBus-avro and libre office on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but whenever I type words like 'সদস্য' or 'প্রিয়' it actually gets typed as 'সদস' and 'পরয়'. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Note: Bangla typing works perfectly even in this forum (as you can see). This problem only arises when I start typing in libre office and google's blogspot websites.

Comment: Which Bangla font you are using in LO ?

Comment: Free sans. 
Whatever font I choose, libre office  always turns it into Free sans font (when I'm using avro phonetic). What should I do?

Comment: Does it happen in text editor too ?

Comment: @orvi Thanks for your support. This bug just got fixed when I changed the locale setting to Bengali (Bangladesh). This option can be accessed under Tools>Options>Language Settings>Languages>locale setting.

I also changed all the Basic Fonts (CTL) to SolaimanLipi. This option can be accessed under Tools>Option>LibreOffice Writer>Basic Fonts (CTL). 

The only thing that bothers me now is that this particular problem still remains unfixed in .blogspot sites only. All the other bangla sites are perfectly alright.

I changed all my browser fonts to SolaimanLipi but still this problem is unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based On comment the solution is here:

Change the locale setting to Bengali (Bangladesh)

This option can be accessed under `Tools>Options>Language Settings>Languages>locale setting` and  changed all the Basic Fonts (CTL) to SolaimanLipi.